# Ubuntu extremely slow on my PC

Tags: java, performance

I'm running Xubuntu on Virtualbox on my Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10.  It used to run ok but then it became very slow.  I'm running it with 4 gigs of RAM.  It's slow to type or click on any GUIs. Here is the output of some of my configuration:

```
weblogic@weblogic-VirtualBox:/usr/apps/das/logs/clientGatewayLogs$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
       vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master rom
       configuration: driver=vboxvideo latency=0


top
top - 19:10:06 up 1 day,  3:22,  8 users,  load average: 6.91, 4.16, 4.29
Tasks: 197 total,   3 running, 194 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 66.7 us,  3.2 sy, 30.2 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  5164976 total,  1385252 free,  1966332 used,  1813392 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  7972816 total,  7972816 free,        0 used.  2875004 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                              
13287 weblogic  20   0 2712544 583656  36064 S 30.8 11.3  12:27.52 java                                                                                                                                                                 
19128 weblogic  20   0  992656  84384  16092 S 30.8  1.6   0:09.31 java                                                                                                                                                                 
19139 weblogic  39  19  130408  80664  54704 R 29.5  1.6   0:02.45 apt-check                                                                                                                                                            
  927 root      20   0  463060 267060  28792 S  3.9  5.2  85:49.92 Xorg                                                                                                                                                                 
12138 weblogic  20   0 2561896 340352  25704 S  1.6  6.6   6:02.46 java                                                                                                                                                                 
 2011 weblogic  20   0  409844  38396  25420 S  1.3  0.7   1:57.25 xfce4-terminal                                                                                                                                                       
 1637 weblogic  20   0  181752   1988   1612 S  0.3  0.0   5:45.94 VBoxClient                                                                                                                                                           
 1764 weblogic  20   0  173104  29256  16596 S  0.3  0.6   4:19.89 xfwm4                                                                                                                                                                
16431 weblogic  20   0 2030472  84612  16188 S  0.3  1.6   0:42.21 java                                                                                                                                                                 
19116 weblogic  20   0   33724   3388   2844 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.35 top                                                                                                                                                                  
    1 root      20   0  185772   6420   4016 S  0.0  0.1   0:08.07 systemd                                                                                                                                                              
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
```

Comment: Windows 2010? What's that?

Comment: Slow in what way? What does Java have to do with this?

Comment: @Yes, Windows I meant Windows 10.

Comment: @Zacharee1, Java may have nothing to do with it, but those are the programs using the most memory.  Ubuntu is slow with any kind of user input, keyboard, mouse movements, selecting new windows, etc.

Comment: Possibly off-topic, but is a dualboot situation better?

Comment: @Mark Yisri, I need both the host and guest running.  This used to work fine for me and on a machine with a SSD and the memory I gave it, it shouldn't be this slow.

Comment: @user994165 What are you trying to do here?